# Custom application for coreFlightSystem: "Could not load cFE application"

Tags: c, embedded, core-flight-system

When I run coreFlightSystem with my custom application, I get the following log message:

```
ES Startup: Loading file: /cf/apps/lls_app.so, APP: LLS_APP
ES Startup: loading directly:/cf/apps/lls_app.so (LLS_APP) -70028.
ES Startup: Could not load cFE application file:/cf/apps/lls_app.so. EC = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

I have checked, and `lls_app.so` is built and placed in the correct location (`build/cpu1/exe/cf/apps/lls_app.so`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Failing to load an application may be caused by a number of issues. A few things to check:

- Check that the application is be generated (the `.so`) and is in the correct directory
- Review the startup script to make sure that the application name and entry location are correct
- Check for warnings such as undefined references when building.

This specific case was caused by a typo in a function name called by the application's `*_AppInit` function. This resulted in an undefined reference warning when building.

Comment: This is probably a self answer to the actual problem, but because it's not specific about that but has a laundry list of other points, it looks to have been read by some to be a random guess from a 3rd party.  Your answer would be better received if you were specific about the actual typo, ie, **show the wrong line of code and explain what it should have been**.   That said, questions that turn out to be about a one-time goof have little lasting value and tend to be closed/removed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the actual code that caused the problem. I was trying to recreate a question that we had on our github issue tracker. This is a fairly common question for us, which is why I put down the laundry list. I don't think the specific typo would add much (even if I had it).

Comment: You haven't even satisfied the requirements for *real* questions and answers.  Fake ones intended to educate others would be held to an even higher standard.  Both question and response have been rightfully downvoted to oblivion and will likely get removed from the site.

Comment: @superdesk as the coder of the app you're having trouble with, I'd also add that this issue could be related to forgetting to correctly name the app in the Makefile. I wasted a couple of hours the first time trying to solve this.

Comment: As a reminder, it's not a "fake question" and [it is ok to answer your own questions.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  But the question certainly does need an actual question at some point, and the offending line would raise the quality. If you're taking something from the CFS mailing list and posting it here, post the answer with it immediately to avoid wasting people's time. Asking both at the same time is ok, but share whatever solutions you get.